# Get iPhone to Vibrate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've been trying to make the iPhone Vibrate using this code:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

But is not working, could it be because I am playing sound at the same time as calling this?

Comment: Just tried it without the sound, still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Keep in mind that this function call only vibrates on the iPhone.  If you run this on an iPod touch, nothing happens.  (Not sure about an iPad.)  http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html

Comment: @BP not true. On the iPod, it will trigger the saw wave sound (or is it square wave?) -- beep boop beep boop.

Comment: I have tried this and also cannot get my phone to vibrate. I have turned on both vibrate settings (Vibrate on Ring and Vibrate on Silent). I am running iOS 6.0.1. Does anyone else have this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should work fine. Has vibration been turned off on the device?

Comment: Checked settings, it's on. Is there any way to test it to make sure it works??

Comment: Are you sure the device can vibrate at all? If you turn the sound switch off and on, does it vibrate?

Comment: Which sound switch? The vibrate one?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the mute toggle on the side.

Comment: Also, don't forget to #import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

Answer (score 15):

If this helps anyone, I discovered that the vibrate command won't work while `AVAudioRecorder` is recording. Getting round this is very simple. You just have to stop your recorder first and resume it afterwards:

```
[recorder stop];
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
[recorder record];
```

This even works if you want to record sound and vibrate in the background using `UIBackgroundModes`.

Comment: :) It's good when you find someone who had exactly the same problem as you!

Answer (score 3):

I'm using that code successfully on iPhone 4. It's not clear from the [documentation of System Sound](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html), but that code works only if the vibration is enabled in Settings.

Of course note that there are two different settings for the vibration: silent mode and normal mode. Toggling the Ring/Silent switch to Silent is not sufficient to enable vibration.

I guess you've already tried enabling the vibration in your device Settings, but worth highlighting this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

On all iPhones that I've tested on (original, 3GS, and 4), it should vibrate. On the iPod touch 1st generation, it'll play a beep through the built-in speaker. On the iPod touch 2nd generation, it won't do anything. On the iPad, it won't do anything either. Those are all the devices I've tested on.