# iOS 7.1 - How to get Phone vibrate using LocalNotification and App is in Background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios7

I need to have some Alarm-Clock Functionallity in my App.

One of them should be to let the Phone vibrate and the Sound play (both max 30s) when the LocalNotification fires and the App is in the Background.

But the Vibration vibes only once (the Sound still playing).
As i said before i need a long Vibration.

How can i do that ?

I followed these Links:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1668/_index.html

http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios

http://www.sagorin.org/ios-playing-audio-in-background-audio/

[Get iPhone to Vibrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373902/get-iphone-to-vibrate)

I did the following Settings:

Targets: Capablilities: 
under *Background Modes* —> Check: *Modes: Audio and AirPlay*

@MyProject-plist:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
    <string>location</string>
</array>
```

@Source-Code:

```
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
```

Comment: Is it really impossible to do that ?

Comment: I think these are handled by OS side.